# How do I authenticate against Active Directory using ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, active-directory, ldap

I am looking for an example with Razor syntax that would go in a cshtml file for ASP.NET Web Pages. The solution I am looking for would exclude writing a C# class in Visual Studio. Our project is not an MVC project, it's a Web Pages project.

I need to prompt the user to enter their username and password for an intranet web app and authenticate them against Active Directory with an LDAP query.

I was hoping there is a built-in Helper in Web Matrix I have overlooked, for example (eg. like the WebSecurity helper, but instead of querying a DB, I'd query an AD server).

Comment: what have you tried or what have you got thus far..? are you familiar with `PrincipalContext` ..here you can find plenty of working examples [C# PrincipalContext Examples](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I searched Google with `+Razor Active Directory ASP.NET` and this was the second hit: http://forums.asp.net/t/1851715.aspx?MVC3+C+using+razor+with+ldap+active+directory+Authentication

Comment: The solution I was looking for would exclude writing a C# class in Visual Studio. I was hoping there was a built-in Helper in Web Matrix, for example (eg. like the WebSecurity helper).   Maybe it doesn't exist, and I need to create a Helper myself using one of the examples for C#/VS and then import it into the Web Pages project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Within Web Matrix, open the NuGet package manager and install the Novell.Directory.Ldap package. Here's an example usage:

```
@using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
@{
    Validation.RequireField("username", "username is required");
    Validation.RequireField("password", "password is required");

    var username = "";
    var userdn   = "";
    var domain = "domain.com";
    var pwd = "";
    var error = "";

    if (IsPost) {
        if (Validation.IsValid()) {
            username = Request["username"];
            userdn   = "cn=" + username + ",ou=Users,o=INTRANET";
            pwd      = Request["password"];

            try {
                LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection();
                ldapConnection.Connect(domain, 389);
                ldapConnection.Bind(userdn, pwd);
            }
            catch (LdapException e) {
                error = e.LdapErrorMessage;
            }
        }
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello LDAP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello LDAP Page</h1>
        @if (IsPost) {
            if (error.IsEmpty()) {
                <p>'@username' was successfully authenticated against <i>@domain</i>!</p>
            }
            else {
                <p>error! @error</p>
            }
        }
        else {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <p><label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("title")</p>

                <p><label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("password")</p>

                <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Login" /></p>
            </fieldset>
            </form> 
        }

    </body>
</html>
```